Extracting the the UTM value that contains mixed characters from Google Sheets via REGEX
I have multiple lines like this one where I need to extract the value associated with the utm_campaign field. As you can see, the value comprises digits, letter  and characters (ex"-")
https://smycampaign?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=paid&utm_campaign=2023-test-campaign&utm_content=img-01-a&utm_id=7677898

So basically, I need to extract 2023-test-campaign into cell B1 using REGEX.
I tried using this, which works on the REGEX101 editor, but not in Google sheets:
(?P<utm_campaign>(?<=utm_campaign=).*?(?=&|\\s|$))


Please [edit] the question to explain what you tried, showing what it did correctly and what it did not do. Please also look up "pertained" in a dictionary and check that it is the correct word.

It is just [?&]utm_campaign=([^\s&]*)

Maybe this will help where cell A1 is housing the URL;
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"_campaign=(.+)&utm_content")


You can use:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"utm_campaign=([^&]+)") 

